# Adding 'type' attribute to a script tag loaded by a dll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu control that is coming from a dll, I just need to reference it.  Its old so the script tag that is **injected** into the page has the 'language' attribute.  I looking for a way to add a 'type' attribute after the page has loaded.

I tried:

```
$("script").attr("type", "text/javascript");
```

but it doesn't work ... any suggestions, or is it even possible?

Comment: Is the script tag injected into the head or body?

Comment: script tag is injected into the body, just under the hidden viewstate input tag.  I'm trying to see if I can get the page to validate, as script tags need the 'type' attribute.

Comment: If it is being added via JavaScript, then it won't be visible to validators, so that isn't going to help it validate. (And the current HTML 5 draft makes the type attribute optional).

Comment: The script tag contains JavaScript for an old menu control that the page is using.  If I had access to the source I could fix it, but as it goes now ... script is added on page load. Site is XHTML 1.0 Transitional

Answer (score 2):

I'm affraid it's not possible to edit a script tag. Because it would mean that the script can be unloaded, which is impossible, because code can already be executed.

So what you could try, is to create a second script tag which has the correct attributes:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "url";
script.type = "text/javascript";
$("head").append(script);
```

Comment: Didn't understand this at first ... but it works fine. Thanks.